# VBA: Insert HyperLink into email body and link back to specific cell in original workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that contains supplier information. The information is stored in a table. The first column of the table has the unique identification number in the form "SR-DDDD"; where D is a digit. The last column of the table is called "Status Updates". This is where information regarding the supplier is to be updated by the user. In a separate folder we have PDF's that are saved. The PDF's relate to the suppliers and the names of the PDF files have the unique identification number contained therein.

**For example:**

Table Value: "SR-2345" -
PDF Name : "Supplier Waterloo - SR-2345.pdf"

**Current Set Up**

Currently the workbook generates an email and asks you to attach a file from the PDF folder mentioned above. It then takes the PDF name and extracts the SR number using a regex expression. I then find the corresponding cell address in the table using the SR number as a parameter to find the row number and a static value as a column number. The column number refers to the "Status Updates" column.

**What I need help with**

I would like to have a hyperlink placed in the email, that will take the user directly to the correct cell in the "Status Updates" column - so that after they review the PDF they can easily enter the information into the table. In the code I have provided I have triangulated the address of the cell, I am just having trouble building the hyperlink. I am also not entirely sure if this is possible, which is why I am reaching out.

Please see my code:

```
Sub ApprovalEmailSupp()

Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim fdInputFile As FileDialog
Dim sInputFile As Variant
Dim sDetails As String
Dim sStrBody As String

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set fdInputFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
Set myAttachments = OutlookMail.Attachments
    
    MsgBox "Note: Only 1 attachment is permitted."
    
    With OutlookMail
        
        .To = "Purchasing Team"
        .CC = Environ("USERNAME") & "@testmail.com"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        
        With fdInputFile
            .Filters.Clear
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .InitialFileName = "SUPPLIER FOLDER PATH"
            If .Show = False Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
        
        For Each sInputFile In fdInputFile.SelectedItems
            .Attachments.Add sInputFile, 1
        Next sInputFile
        
        .Subject = Replace(myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName, ".pdf", "")
        
        Dim sRequestNumber As String
        sRequestNumber = ReqNumber(myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName)
        
        Dim rFindSupplierRequest As Range
        Set rFindSupplierRequest = Sheet3.Range("A:A").Find(What:="SR-" & sRequestNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        If Not rFindSupplierRequest Is Nothing Then
            Dim lFoundSupplier As Long
            lFoundSupplier = rFindSupplierRequest.Row
            
            Dim vAddress As Variant
            vAddress = Sheet3.Cells(lFoundSupplier, 36).Address
        End If
            
        sDetails = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri><a href=""" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "\" & Sheet3.Range(vAddress) & """>Status Updates </a>"
                    
        .HTMLBody = sDetails
        .Display
        
  End With

End Sub
```

There are no errors that pop up when I run the macro and send the email. However the hyperlink just takes me into the workbook - It does NOT take me to the specified cell.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to do this directly.

Comment: Hi There - OK, I see. Thank you for taking a look anyways.